# Ruby - epoch time with milliseconds to local time string

Tags: ruby

I have the following UNIX epoch timestamp - `1475001600029`

I need to convert it into `local` date-time of format  - `2016/09/28 00:01:13.536`

Things I've tried

```
irb(main):005:0> Time.at(1475001600079)
=> 48710-12-11 00:11:19 +0530    # gives a weird value for year


irb(main):010:0> Time.strptime(1475001600079.to_s, '%Q')
NoMethodError: undefined method `strptime' for Time:Class
        from (irb):10
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

How to go about this ?

RUby version is - `ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `Time.at(1475001600079 / 1000.0)`.

The epoch time in ruby is in seconds, not milliseconds.

As to the `NoMethodError`, you need to `require 'time'` before you call `Time::strptime`.

Finally the format you need:

```
Time.at(1475001600079 / 1000.0).strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%3N')
```

Comment: @Aetherus the format required is of the type `2016/09/28 00:01:13.536`

Comment: @user3206440 Updated

Answer (score 17):

Instead of doing an explicit division by 1000, you could also consider using the `:millisecond` option of `Time.at()`

```rb
> Time.at(0, 1475001600029, :millisecond)
2016-09-27 18:40:00 +0000
```