# Conversion from epoch to datetime is incorrect

Tags: ruby, unix, unix-timestamp, epoch

I've been using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7816368/4214184) to convert epoch time to DateTime. I have this epoch number:

```
epoch = 1549626705942
```

and do:

```
Time.at(epoch).to_datetime
```

However, I get this as the result:

```
#<DateTime: 51075-09-19T08:45:42+02:00 ((20376082j,24342s,0n),+7200s,2299161j)>
```

I'm using Ruby version 2.5.3p105 and my clock is set to the current year. This epoch value evaluates to today's date (February 2nd, 2019) yet I get a year 51075. Really not sure what's going on.

It's also weird because, when I enter my timestamp at a site like [this one](https://www.epochconverter.com/) I get today's date but [here](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) I get the same result as my Ruby code.

Edit: I tried to remove the last 3 numbers of this date and got a correct date. So is it that there are 2 epoch "formats" so to say?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are passing miliseconds to the `Time::at()` method. You should pass seconds there. Link to docs is [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Time.html#method-c-at).

To retrieve Epoch value(in seconds), use [`Time#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Time.html#method-i-to_i)

**UPD**

This will work for you:

```rb
Time.at(0, your_epoch_milliseconds, :millisecond)
```

Comment: Is there a way to also pass milliseconds and get the correct datetime?

Comment: And how do you retrive miliseconds?

Comment: I retrieved the epoch API with milliseconds from an API. So I can either trim this integer (will trimming the last 3 numbers always work?) or configure Ruby so it correctly converts that number into DateTime with the current format. 

I'm not interested in retrieving but converting an epoch value already given to me.

Comment: Thanks, can you reference the resource where you got/figured this solution? I'm looking at ".at" rdoc and can't find any reference to this.

Comment: I gave you the reference in the answer. Here is copy-paste http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Time.html#method-c-at

Comment: Was wondering how is it different than this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39929299/4214184

Comment: Well, you can, of course, devide your milliseconds value by 1000.0. But there is already built-in feature in ruby to rich desired result. Take a look closer on description of `Time::at` method, this line - `at(seconds, milliseconds, :millisecond)`